# Is there a maximum size to NSDocumentsDirectory? Are the contents accessible outside the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, nsdocumentdirectory

Is there a limit to the amount of data that we can put to the NSDocumentsDirectory? My application allows photo and video capturing and I am saving this data to the NSDocumentsDirectory. Can I keep on adding images and videos to the app then? Also, are these images and videos accessible outside the app? Can we delete them using iTunes? Help please!

Answer (score 1):

You should start with reading apples [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672) for file system access.

And remember: Whenever something in the apple docs reads like a hint or a recommendation, it actually says "do it that way or we won't let your app into our store".